# How to approach this Integral with nested exponents?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've reduced a problem down to:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (x^2 - 1)^n ~dx$$

$n$ can be any natural number. How to proceed?  I already did a Trig Sub to get here, so not imagining I need to do another one..  Maybe I do though?  This is supposed to be an Integration by Parts problem, though not sure.

Comment: The further substitution $u = x^2 - 1$ gets you an integral of the form
$$
\frac 12 \int_a^b \frac{u^n}{\sqrt{u+1}}\,du
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann don't you need a du=2x available do to that?  can you show how the du is pulled out?

Comment: It is easy to use the binomial formula here.

Comment: @bgcode $du = 2xdx \implies dx = \frac{1}{2x}\,du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u+1}}du$

Comment: @BenGrossmann That makes sense, but how is that integral any easier to solve?  That's actually rather similar to the form of the integral I started with!

Comment: Side note - if you did the trigonometric substitution, did you also apply it to the limits? Also, maybe it would help to show us the original integral - it could be that, by using partial integration you can make a simple recurrence formula.

Comment: The original integral  $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$

Comment: Update: The original integral would've been directly solvable with Integration by Parts (which is probably why @BenGrossmann updated it to the starting form, but still curious about solving this binomial one without that.)

Answer (score 4):

For any specific $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you can expand and get an elementary integral, and if you want a general formula that works for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so again expanding with the binomial theorem $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^k b^{n-k}$ we get
$$(x^2-1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{2k} (-1)^{n-k}$$
so that by linearity of the integral
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{2k} (-1)^{n-k} dx = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{n-k} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x^{2k}  dx =\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{n-k} \frac{\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that $n$ is a natural number, then use [the binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to expand the integrand into a summation.